# Python list comprehension trick

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

It's probably a silly question, but...

```
list = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(i):
        list.append(i)
print(list)

list2 = [[i]*i for i in range(1, 5)]
print(list2)
```

With following code my output is like

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

I understand why the second one looks like this, but are there any tricks to get the first list with comprehension?
**P.S.**
Python 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> list2 = [i for i in range(1, 5) for j in range(i)]
>>> list2
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Trick is to put similar `for` loops in same order inside the list comprehension (and since you do not need list of lists, do not create those).

Answer (score 3):

`[i for i in range(5) for j in range(i)]` should do the trick.
You can use multiple `for`s in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

While I prefer the double `for`, you could also use `reduce` using `list2`:

```
list1 = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [[i] * i for i in range(1, 5)])
print list1
# [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

From your snippet can I add `sum` to get the same output:

```
>>> sum([[i]*i for i in range(1, 5)], [])
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>>
```

or using reduce:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [[i]*i for i in range(1, 5)])
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>>
```

Let me know if you don't like this solution. I will remove it.

Comment: No, it is useful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools,

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

list2 = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, i) for i in range(1, 5)))

print(list2)
```

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]

[Program finished]
```